# Java stream concatenation after each function

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When we concatenate streams using `Stream.concat` is it possible to run a function whenever a stream gets over?

e.g.

I'm creating streams out of multiple files using `Files.lines`. Now whenever a file is read completely, I need to delete it.

Comment: Just run it on the original stream before concatenation?

Comment: Please give an example, I don't understand your "whenever a stream gets over"

Comment: Let me explain my use case

Comment: what do you mean by 'gets over'?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I think he means that he wants to run a function whenever a stream terminates. And he wants that function to still run when the streams have been concatenated. Some like this pseudo-code: `Stream.concat(Stream.of(1).onTermination(() -> ...), Stream.of(2).onTermination(() -> ...));`

Comment: @FaizHalde can't you simply delete the files when the streams are done? I don't think such functionality exists.

Answer (score 4):

The close handlers of a stream composed via `Stream.concat` are executed when the resulting stream is closed. Note that close handlers in general require that the code using the stream closes the stream, e.g.

```
try(Stream<String> s=Stream.concat(Files.lines(path1), Files.lines(path2))) {
    s.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

for proper closing and

```
try(Stream<String> s=Stream.concat(
        Files.lines(path1).onClose(()->{
            try { Files.delete(path1); }
            catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
        }),
        Files.lines(path2).onClose(()->{
            try { Files.delete(path2); }
            catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
        }))
    ) {

    s.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

for deleting the files afterwards. But in this case, the resulting stream’s close handler will invoke the source stream’s close handlers, so this doesn’t delete the files immediately after use, but after the entire operation, so it’s not much different to

```
try(Closeable c1=() -> Files.deleteIfExists(path1);
    Closeable c2=() -> Files.deleteIfExists(path2);
    Stream<String> s=Stream.concat(Files.lines(path1), Files.lines(path2)); ) {

    s.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If you want a timely deletion of the files, you have to use `flatMap`. The sub-streams will be closed immediately after use, regardless of whether the “outer” stream will be closed:

```
Stream.of(path1, path2)
      .flatMap(path -> {
            try { return Files.lines(path).onClose(()->{
                try { Files.delete(path); }
                catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
            }); }
            catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
        })
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

To demonstrate the difference,

```
try(Stream<String> s=Stream.concat(
        Stream.of("foo").onClose(()->System.out.println("foo closed")),
        Stream.of("bar").onClose(()->System.out.println("bar closed")) )) {
    s.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

will print

```
foo
bar
foo closed
bar closed
```

whereas

```
Stream.of("foo", "bar")
    .flatMap(x -> Stream.of(x).onClose(()->System.out.println(x+" closed")) )
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

will print

```
foo
foo closed
bar
bar closed
```

Comment: the suggestion about flatMap is awesome. +1

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using Stream.onClose(). Like Stream.concat().onClose()

Comment: The runnable is not running somehow

Comment: @RishiSaraf onClose is a different thing here, it will not work.